# How to add custom servables in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have been looking for a way to serve pre-training (non-tensorflow) models with Tensorflow Serving. It seems like the only way to do it is by implementing a custom servable. But I couldn't find good tutorial to do it. Tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/custom_servable) doesn't really show how to do it. I don't even know where to start or where all each file should be placed.

Has anyone tried to build a custom servable? Is there any link or example that you can share here?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am searching for the same thing